# Soldering problem when changing component on tablet board

Tags: pcb, soldering, repair, solder-paste

I needed to change demaged Schottky SMD diode (2.2x1.2mm) at chineese tablet board. But I was not able to **melt solder** even I used hot gun at 400°C or soldering tip at 480°C. Finally I more or less "unstick" diode (solder was not liquid), put there lead solder and soldered new diode. But the quality of connection is rather poor but working.

What solder is used at these boards, is there some covering lacquer, resin or is there so huge heat sink via PCB I'm not able to melt it without preheating? I don't think the pads has reason to have huge heat sick as it's low current step-up converter for display (tiny power choke). And seems neither component solder was not affected too.

Comment: No, it's just lead-free solder.

Comment: [Just guessing](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/138111/how-to-solder-lcd-display-pins#comment279387_138111)

Comment: @put-on-hold: slightly reworded but provided link does not relates  question. I asked just about desoldering action and provided hopefully knowledge when I described what to do and even notice that it's fixed now. I tried to get experience if anybody had similar problem because it's rather weird.

Answer (score 1):

The diode may be connected at one (or even both) sides to large copper masses in the form of a ground or power plane.  Consequently it will take a lot of heating to melt the solder.  Not higher temperature, just applying heat for longer.

In this situation it is often good to pre-heat the whole board, either on a soldering hotplate, or in a reflow oven.

The other possibility is that the diode is on the "underside" of the board and may have been glued in place before soldering to hold it in place.

Comment: I wrote that I don't expect huge heat sink at least on the one end (Schottky diode in step-up converter for display, choke is tiny, i.e.low current). When I tried to desolder using heat gun neither neighbourgh components had no tend to melt. Do you think the board itself is manufactured from material with large thermal conductivity to make huge cooler ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to melt some of your own solder wire on the solders you can't melt. The solders kind of merge together. You can now easily heat up the solder and it should melt.